# Display problem on a mobile device, but only on a few phones. Section blinks/ flashes on the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, display

**Edit: The animation cause was the issue. So any ideas how to fix it?**

`animation: pulse 2.5s infinite cubic-bezier(0.55, 0, 0, 0.7);`

I've got a problem. I tried to create a hotspot map, and it's working fine right now, but I have some display issues when I check it on two phones. The section starts to blink like on the screen.

Page: https://hoffmannteile.de/

[image]

On other phones, everything is okay. I don't know if it's a resolution problem or something else because when I try it on Chrome with different resolutions in Device Mode, it doesn't even blink once. I have to fix it because one of them is my boss's phone :)

```js
           function showInfo(hotspoterId) {
            var countryNameElement = document.getElementById("country-name");
            var cityNameElement = document.getElementById("city-name");
            var addressInfoElement = document.getElementById("address-info");
            var telInfoElement = document.getElementById("tel-info");
            var telInfo2Element = document.getElementById("tel-info-2");
            var callButtonElement = document.getElementById("call-button");
    
            switch (hotspoterId) {
                case 2:
                    countryNameElement.textContent = "Belgien";
                    cityNameElement.textContent = "PEER";
                    addressInfoElement.textContent = "Postleitzahl: 3900";
                    telInfoElement.textContent = "Tel: 0032 411271367";
                    telInfo2Element.textContent = "";
                    callButtonElement.href = "tel:0032411271367";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    countryNameElement.textContent = "Niederlande";
                    cityNameElement.textContent = "ZAANDAM";
                    addressInfoElement.textContent = "Postleitzahl: 1505";
                    telInfoElement.textContent = "Tel: 0031 612936220";
                    telInfo2Element.textContent = "";
                    callButtonElement.href = "tel:0031612936220";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    countryNameElement.textContent = "Östrreich";
                    cityNameElement.textContent = "ILZ";
                    addressInfoElement.textContent = "Postleitzahl: 8262";
                    telInfoElement.textContent = "Tel: 0043 6602273462";
                    telInfo2Element.textContent = "";
                    callButtonElement.href = "tel:00436602273462";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    countryNameElement.textContent = "Deutschland";
                    cityNameElement.textContent = "GÖRLITZ";
                    addressInfoElement.textContent = "Postleitzahl: 02826";
                    telInfoElement.textContent = "Tel: 0049 15905517928";
                    telInfo2Element.textContent = "";
                    callButtonElement.href = "tel:004915905517928";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    countryNameElement.textContent = "Polen";
                    cityNameElement.textContent = "PIOTRKÓW TRYB.";
                    addressInfoElement.textContent = "Postleitzahl: 97300";
                    telInfoElement.textContent = "Tel: 0048 501102760";
                    telInfo2Element.textContent = "Tel: 0048 501102760";
                    callButtonElement.href = "tel:0048 501102760";
                    break;
            }
    
            document.getElementById("map-info").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("map-overlay").style.display = "block";
        }
    
        function closeInfo() {
            document.getElementById("map-info").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("map-overlay").style.display = "none";
        }
```

```css
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;500;700;900&display=swap');

    .map-section {
      background-color: transparent;
      padding: 20px;
      max-width: 800px;
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      margin: auto;
      display: block;

    }

    .map-container {
        position: relative;
    }

    .hotspoters {
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: space-around;
      align-items: center;
      pointer-events: none;
    }

    .hotspoters h3{
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      font-size: 2vmin;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .clickspoter{
      display: flex;
      width: 6vmin;
      height: 6vmin;
      background-color: #6200ff8f;
      z-index: 2;
      cursor: pointer; 
      pointer-events: auto;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .hotspoter {
    position: relative;
    width: 2vmin;
    height: 2vmin;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(131, 4, 4, 0.7);
    background: #ad0000;
    cursor: pointer;
    animation: pulse 2.5s infinite cubic-bezier(0.55, 0, 0, 0.7);
    pointer-events: auto;
    
    &:hover {
      animation: none;
    }
    
    &.deactivate {
      color: #000;
      background: #999;
      animation: none;
    }
      
    }
        /*SPOTS POSITION*/
    /*belgien*/
    .hot2{
      top: 36.5%;
      left: 10%;
      position: absolute;

    }
    /*niederlande*/
    .hot3{
      top: 23.5%;
      left: 8.7%;
      position: absolute;
    }
    /*osterreich*/
    .hot4{
      top: 82%;
      left: 58%;
      position: absolute;
    }
    /*deutschland*/
    .hot5{
      top: 38%;
      left: 51%;
      position: absolute;
    }
    /*polen*/
    .hot6{
      top: 35%;
      left: 72%;
      position: absolute;
    }

    /*COUNTRY POSITION*/

    /*belgien*/
    .ctr2{
      top: 39.5%;
      left: 5%;
      position: absolute;
    }
    /*niederlande*/
    .ctr3{
      top: 26.5%;
      left: 11%;
      position: absolute;
    }
    /*osterreich*/
    .ctr4{
      top: 74%;
      left: 50%;
      position: absolute;
    }
    /*deutschland*/
    .ctr5{
      top: 40%;
      left: 25%;
      position: absolute;
    }
    /*polen*/
    .ctr6{
      top: 26%;
      left: 70%;
      position: absolute;
    }

    /*styles for SVG*/
    .schweiz, .belgien, .niederlande, .ostrreich, .deutschland, .polen {
      fill: #FFFFFF;
      stroke: #610000;
      stroke-miterlimit: 10;
      transition: fill 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
    }

    .schweiz:hover, .belgien:hover, .niederlande:hover, .ostrreich:hover, .deutschland:hover, .polen:hover {
      fill: #ad0000;
      opacity: 0.5;
    }

    .noclick {
      fill: #E8E8E8;
      stroke: #7A0000;
      stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    }

    .info-box {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      top: 100%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translateX(-50%);
      background-color: #fff;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      padding: 30px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .map-info {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
      padding: 30px;
      background-color: #fff;
      box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      z-index: 95;
      border: #ad0000;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 3px;
    }

    /* Styl dla tła z widocznym efektem overlay */
    .map-overlay {
      display: none;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
      z-index: 90;
    }

    /* Styl dla przycisku zamykającego okno */
    .map-btn {
      position: absolute;
      top: 10px;
      right: 15px;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-weight: 900;
      font-size: 20px;
    }

    .map-btn:hover{
      color: #ad0000;
      transform: scale(0.8);
    }

    /* Styl dla div.map-details */
    .map-details {
      width: 60vmin;
      padding: 0vmin;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    /* Styl dla małego nagłówka z nazwą kraju */
    .country-name {
      color: #333;
      font-weight: 600;
      font-size: 2vmin;
      margin-top: 1vmin;
    }

    /* Styl dla zwykłego nagłówka z nazwą miasta */
    .city-name {
      color: #000;
      font-weight: 700;
      font-size: 4vmin;
      margin-top: 0.5vmin;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    /* Styl dla paragrafu z kodem pocztowym i numerem telefonu */
    .address-info {
      color: #555;
      font-size: 2.5vmin;
      margin-top: 0.5vmin;
    }

    .tel-info {
      color: #555;
      margin-top: -1.5vmin;
      font-size: 2.5vmin;
    }

    /* Styl dla guzika */
    .call-button {
      background-color: #ad0000;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 10px;
      border: none;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 2vmin;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: background-color 0.3s, border 0.3s, color 0.3s;
      margin-top: 10px;
      border: 2px solid #ad0000;
      font-weight: 600;
    }

    /* Efekt hover dla guzika */
    .call-button:hover {
      background-color: #fff;
      border: 2px solid #ad0000;
      color: #ad0000;
      font-weight: 600;
    }

    @keyframes pulse {
      to {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 3vmin rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
      }
    }

    @media (max-width:490px){
    .call-button {
        font-size: 4vmin;
    }

    .tel-info {
        font-size: 4vmin;
    }

    .address-info {
        font-size: 4vmin;
    }

    .city-name {
        font-size: 6vmin;
    }

    .country-name{
        font-size: 3.5vmin;
    }

    .hotspoters h3 {
    font-size: 2.3vmin;
    }

    .map-container{
        padding-top: 12%;
        padding-bottom: 12%;    
    }

            /*SPOTS POSITION*/
    /*belgien*/
    .hot2{
      top: 40.5%;
      left: 10%;
    }
    /*niederlande*/
    .hot3{
      top: 31%;
      left: 9.5%;
    }
    /*osterreich*/
    .hot4{
      top: 73%;
      left: 58%;
    }
    /*deutschland*/
    .hot5{
      top: 42%;
      left: 51%;
    }
    /*polen*/
    .hot6{
      top: 38%;
      left: 72%;
    }

    /*COUNTRY POSITION*/

    /*belgien*/
    .ctr2{
      top: 42%;
      left: 5%;
    }
    /*niederlande*/
    .ctr3{
      top: 32.5%;
      left: 11.5%;
    }
    /*osterreich*/
    .ctr4{
      top: 68%;
      left: 49%;
    }
    /*deutschland*/
    .ctr5{
      top: 40%;
      left: 25%;
    }
    /*polen*/
    .ctr6{
      top: 30%;
      left: 70%;
    }
}

  </style>
```

```html
<section class="map-section">
    <div class="map-container">

        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 498.1 315.8">
            <path d="m71.1 181.4-2-3.5a137 137 0 0 1-.3-6.4l3.2-3.1 3-3.6c.3-.3 2.7-.3 3.1-.3l-.4-7.1c4.5-.2 3 .5 3-3.7-.2-3.8.5-2.9-3.2-2.8l2.8-6c0-2.5-.3-6-.4-8.5h-.1l-.2-3-6.8-6.1-6.8-6.1-3.4.1-3 3.1-.3.3-3.6.1-.1-3.2-10.1-2.6c0-.3-2.8 0-2.9 0l-3.2 3.1.2 3.2-10.1.5c-4 .1-2.9.8-3.3-3.1l-3.5-2.8-3.4.2-.2-3.5-3.4.2-3.2 3.6-3.5-3.3.2 3.4-6.3 3.2.1 3.2.3 6.2 3.3 3c.4 0 .3 2.3.3 2.6v.7l3.1-.2 3.1-.1h.2l.3 6.4 6.5-.3c.4-.3.2 2.9.3 3v.3l3.7 6.1c2.9-.2 6.9-.2 9.8-.5l.5 9.7-3 2.9-.2.2 3.5 3.3 6.7-.3-.2-3.5 3.4-.2.1 3.5 3.3 2.7.2.2.2 3.2 3.3 2.9.2.2.1 2.4v.6l3.2-.1c1.7 1.6 5.2 4.7 7 6.1l.2 3.2 3.2-3.4 3.4-.1.7-.4s1.6-5.7 1.4-5.8z" class="belgien"></path>
            <path d="M82.7 188.4c3.9-.2 2.9.4 2.8-3.3l-.3-6.3-.2-3.4-6.7-6-.2-4.9-2.6.1c-.4-.3-3.3 3.6-3.5 3.8l-3.2 3.1.3 6.4 2 3.5c.1.1-1.5 5.8-.8 5.5 3.9.8 9.3 2.5 13.3 3a12 12 0 0 0-.9-1.5z" class="noclick"></path>
            <path d="m55.8 121.5.1 3.2c.2-.1 3.9.1 3.8-.4l2.8-3.1h.2l3.4-.1 3.3 3c2.3 1.9 8 7.1 10.3 9.2l.2 3c.2.1 0-1 .1-1 .2-.3 6.3-2.9 5.8-3.5l.5-.2-.2-3.2-.6-12.1 5.9-3.4 9.5-3.5 3.1 2.9 9.6-.5 3.2-.1.1-.4c.3.1 2.7-9.4 2.9-9.5l-.2-3.2-3.1-2.8L119 93c-.2-.2.3-.5.4-.7l-.6-12 3-.2v-.4h.2l-.5-9.1 2.7-3.1.4-.4-2.1-1.8-2.6 2.4-3.2.2-.6-12.7-6.7.3-3 3.6-6.6 3.3-.3-6.5-3.4 3.6-3.1.1-3.4.2-6.6 3.3-3.2 3.4.3 6.2.7 12.9-6.2 6.5-6.7.3-.3-6.2 3.2-3.5-3.4.1 6.4-6.5-.2-3.2L70 70c-9 .4-5.5-.9-9.8 6.8l.3 6.2-3 3.5.1 3-3.6.2.2 3.2-3 3.4-6.7.3.3 6.4c3.8 0 3.3-1.4 3.5 2.8l-6.3 3.5-.3-6.2-3.6.2.6 12.4 3.6-.2 3.1 3.1.2.2 10.2 2.7z" class="niederlande"></path>
            <path d="M327.1 244.9h.2l2.3-1.1c0-.4-3.6-4-3.9-4.4l.9-2.8c-2.5-3.5-1.6-2.6-5.7-2.5l-3.2-.7-5-2.3-1-1.9-2-1.8-1.8-2.7c-2.1-.3-7.4.3-9.5.3-.7-.5-2.9-2.7-3.7-3l-12.5.6c-.8.7-2.4 2.3-2.8 3.3l.1 3.2-3 3.3-12.7.6-1.3-.6-2.4-2.2c-.6-.2-2.5-.1-3.1-.1l.2 3.2-9.8.5.1 3-5.7 6.6-9.9.4.5 9.3 3.6 3.3.1 2.9.2 3.2 3.1 3 .3 6.3-3 .2.2 3-.9-.7v.1l-2.7-2.2-.3-6.3-6.3-2.9-3 .1.2 3.2-3.6-3-12.7.6-3.1 3.3-3 .1-3.4.2-3.2-3-3.2 3.3-6.5.3c0-.6-.2-2.6-.1-3.2l-6.2-2.9-3.2 6.5-3 .1c-4.2 3.6-2.1 4.2-6.5.3l-3.2.1-1.5-1.4-5.2-4.6-3.2.2-2.9 3.3-.9-.4v2.9l.8-.1 2.7 3.1-.7 2.2 2.4 1.2-.3 3.8c1.5.9 4.4 3.5 5.7 4.8l12.7-.6 3.2-.1.3 6.3 6.5-.3 6-3.4-.2-3.2 3.2-.2 3.4 3 9.7-.5 6.2-.3 6.3 5.7.5.4.2 3 3.2 3 3.5 2.8 6.2-.3 9.6-.4 3.4 3.2 2.8-.2c.2 0 .7 0 .8.2l5.5-1.9 2.8-.1 3.9 4.2 6.4-.3 3.8 2.6.7-2.8 4.4-1.9 3.9.7c-.5-.6 2.1-5 2.3-5.6h.6l12.9-.6c2.7.2 5.8-1.2 8.3-2.1l3.7.7 4-3.5c.1-.1 2.2-5.4 2.5-5-.1-.3 2.9-.2 3-.3l2.6-6.3-.3-6.1h.5v-.4c3.4-.4 3.1.9 2.9-2.9l-.2-3-3.6-3-.2-3.2h.4v-.3l3.8-.2 2.9-1.6-.5 1.5c.3-.2.1 1.2.2 1.2l3.2.7c0-.2-.4-1.8-.1-1.9v-.2l2.6-3c-1.4-3.4-3-8.8-5.2-11.7l2-.9z" class="ostrreich"></path>
            <path d="m102.5 256.7 2.6 2.2-.1-3 6.6 2.7 3.5-.2 15.6-.7 6.6-.3.2 3.4 6.2-.2.1 2.9 6.6 2.9 2.9-3.3 3.2-.2 5.8 5.2.9.8 3.2-.1c4.4 3.9 2.2 3.3 6.5-.3l3-.1 3.2-6.5 6.2 2.9c-.1.6.2 2.6.1 3.2l6.5-.3 3.2-3.3 3.2 3 3.4-.2 3-.1 3.1-3.3 12.7-.6 3.6 3-.2-3.2 3-.1 6.3 2.9.3 6.3 3.6 2.8-.2-3c4.1-.2 2.8.3 2.8-3.5l-.2-3-.6-.6-2.5-2.4-.3-6.1c-.6-.6-3.1-2.7-3.6-3.3l-.5-9.3 9.9-.4 5.7-6.6-.1-3 9.8-.5-.2-3.2-2-2.6-3-3.7c-1.5-1-4-3.4-5-4.9l-.3-.4-3.1.1-3.3-2.8-7-12.2-3.9-3.1c.2-2.1-.3-6.9-.6-9l-2.5-3.5-3.8-2.5-.3-6.4-2.6-.2-4.1-5.6-.4-7c.5-.3 3.6 2.9 3.9 3.2l.2 3.2 5.9-3.6c.2-.1 3.4 3 3.6 3.2l5.9-.6.3-.1 4.2-2.8 1.8-.7 3.4-.1 2.3-3.9 3.9-.2 8.4-5.9c1.8-1.4 4.9-4.5 6.3-6.3l6.7-3.6c.3.1 3.4 3 3.8 3.2l.2 3.2 2.6-.3c0-.2 3.1-3.2 3.2-3.4l-.6-12.2 2.8-3.3c-3.6 0-2.9 1-3.1-2.8l-.7-15.7-3.8-6.2-.1-3.2-.3-3.3 3.3-3.3-3.2.1h-.2l-3.1-3-.1-3-3.4-3-3.6-6.2c1.7-1.5 4.7-4.8 6.2-6.6l-.3-6.1c-.3-4.5-.2-10.8-.5-15.4l-9.7.4-.3-6.4-.3-6.3-9.6.5-.2-3.2-3.2-2.8c-.2-4.2.5-3.1-3.5-3l-2.9 3.3-6.5.3c-3.2 1.6-9.5 4.9-12.5 6.7l-3.2-3 .2 3.2-12.9.6-6.6-2.9 3.5-.2c-.1-3.7-.7-2.8 2.9-3.1l-.3-6.5-6.5.3-2.8 3.5-3.5-6.2-6.4.3-.2-3.2-6.4.3-.2-3.2 3.2-3.3a97.5 97.5 0 0 1-6.9-5.9l-1-.8-1.4 1.3 1.3-1.4-2.2-1.7c-.1-.1-5.8.5-5.6 0h-.6l-2.9-2.6-2.8.1c0-.9-.2-.6-.9-.6l.5 9.5 3.1 2.8.2 3.2-6.3 3.5-3 .1c.3 3.8-.8 3.2 3.2 3l.3 6.3 6.6 2.9-2.8 3.1 2.5 1.8 3.4 4.8-1.7 3.4-1.7-2.9-1.5-3.1c-3.1.2-7.5-.5-10.6-.4l.6 12.7-3 3.3.1 2.9-3.5-5.7-.3-6.4-3.2.1.2 3.2-3 .1-.2-3.2 2.9-3.3-6.6-2.9-15.8.7.2 3.2-3.1 3.3c.3 4-.6 3.1 3.4 3l.2 3.2 3.3 2.8-.4.4-2.7 3.1.5 9.1h-.2v.4l-3 .2.6 12-.4.5v.2l-2.5 2.8 3.1 2.8.2 3.2-2.7 9.4c-.2 0-.2.4-.2.5l-12.8.6-3.1-2.9-9.5 3.5-5.9 3.4.2 2.8.6 12.4-.5.2v.4l-5.8 3.1v1l.4 8.5-2.8 6c3.7 0 3-1 3.2 2.8-.1 4.2 1.5 3.6-3 3.7l.6 12c1.6 1.5 5.1 4.5 6.7 6.1l.5 9.7c0 3.7 1.2 3.1-2.8 3.3l6.8 11.7 3.4 3 6.3 2.9 6.7-.3 3.1 2.8 6.5-.3 3 3 .3.3-9.2 9.7-2.7 6.5.1 3-3.3 3.3.5 9.2.2 3.2-3.1 3.3.3 6.2.2.1.5.9z" class="deutschland"></path>
            <path d="m492.1 148.9-2.4-1-.2-4 2.3-1.2-5.9-6.9-2.5-4.6-4.7-3c2.1-3.2 2-2-.2-5l1.7-9.2-1.1-1.2c-.5-1.3 1.3-10.2 1.5-11.7l-5.7-1-2.7-3.7 11.4-8.4c0-.4 1.2-3.1 1.2-3.4l.7-2.2c-.2-2.2-.1-11-1.5-12.8l-1.2-3.4-5.7-7-1.9-2.2-.4-9.1-2.5-2-1.3-4.6-.3-6.7-7.1-5-4.8-1-5.6-3.5-.2-.1 2.2-3.7-3.5.2 1-.5.9-4.5c-.5-2.2-1.3-6-2.5-8l-2.6-5.2-5.7-1.7-5 1.9-2.6 3.5-1.1 1.3-10.1.5h-.8l-1-2.5-2.7-3.5c-1.8.5-6 1.4-7.9 1.2.2 4-.3 2.8 3.4 2.8l-2.9 6.3-3.1 3.3-6.2.3-.5-9.3L393 14l.2 3.2-5.4 4.7 5.7 1.7.2 2.9-3 3.5-3 .2.5 9.2-9.7.5-.1-3.2-3.2.1-9.3 3.6-3.5-3-.5-9.5-3.2-2.8-.2-3.2-9.7.5-3 3.3-3.2.2-6.4-2.9-3 3.3-3.2.2c.2 4 .5 2.7-3.1 3.1l-3.1 3.5-3.4-3.2a75.6 75.6 0 0 1-5.9 6.8l-3 3.1-3.2.2-3 3.3-3.2.2c0 3.8 1.1 3.1-2.9 3.3l-9.7.5-6.2 3.5-2.9 6.5-2.8 3.1 3.1 2.8.2 3.4-.9-.4-4.7.2-3.6-4.2c-.4 5.5.2 11.6.4 17.1a64.5 64.5 0 0 1-6.2 6.6l3.6 6.2 3.4 3 .1 3 3.1 3h.2l3.2-.1-3.5 3 .2 3.2.1 3.2 3.8 6.2.7 15.7c.2 3.7-.6 2.9 3.1 2.8l-2.8 3.3.6 12.2c.3-.2 1.4-1.8 1.6-2.2l4.6-.9 3.1-.1.6 12.2 3.2-.2 3.4 3 3.2-.2 6.4 2.9h.4l6-.3 3.4 3-6.1 6.6h.5l6-.3c.1-.1 3.3 2.8 3.4 2.8l3.5 6-.6-3.6.8-1.6 2.4-1.5 3.3.4-3.4-1.3-.3-2c2.3.6 7.6 0 10 0l3.4 2.8c.2-.1.3-.7.4-.9l2.7-2.4c2 2.7 7.3 10.3 10 12.2l6.6 2.7 6.4-.3 3.2 3 6.7 5.8h.4l6-.2 3.4 3.2c.3-.1 0-1.5.1-1.7l2.7-2.5 2.4-1.2c.2-.1 4.3-1.2 4.2-1.5l.1.1 3.1 2.7.3 6.3.4-.4v-1l1.8-1.6-.1-4.4 7-3 3.3 3.5 3-.1 3.1-3.1.4 9.2c.3.3 6.5-4.3 6.8-4.5l4-.4 4.6-5.1 3.7 6.2h.2l2.8-.1c3.1 2.5 7.1 6.2 10.1 8.8l3.2-.1 5.3-.2h.9l1.2 4.6 3.2-4.8-.4-3.3.7-2.6-.3-6.3c.4-2.6 1.5-8.4 2.3-10.9l2.6-3.7 3.4-1c1-2.2 3.2-7.1 4.3-9.1l6.2-5.8 6.2.5 3.5-2.7 2-6.9-2.5-4.2z" class="polen"></path>
            <path d="M278.7 153.6c.1.3-2.7.4-2.8.5l-.2-3.2c-.2-.3-3.7-3-3.8-3.2l-6.7 3.6a46.9 46.9 0 0 1-6.3 6.3l-8.4 5.9-3.9.2-2.3 3.9-3.4.1-1.8.7-4.2 2.8-.3.1-5.9.6c-.2-.2-3.3-3.3-3.6-3.2l-5.9 3.6-.2-3.2c-.3-.2-3.5-3.4-3.9-3.2l.4 7 4.1 5.6 2.6.2.3 6.4 3.8 2.5 2.5 3.5c.4 2.2.7 6.9.6 9l3.9 3.1 7 12.2 3.3 2.8 3.1-.1 2.4 2.9c2.9 2 5.8 5.9 7.9 8.7.2.1 3-.1 3.1.1l2.4 2.2c.9 1 6.4.3 7.5.3l6.4-.3 3-3.3-.1-3.2c.4-1 2-2.6 2.8-3.3l12.7-.6 3.5 3 9.4-.5.1.1 1.8 2.7 2 1.8 1 1.9c1 .5 5.8 2.7 6.9 2.7l2.4-5.6.4-5 2.6-4.3c2.5-1 7.5-2.7 10.1-3.3l6.6-5 3-.9 3.2 1.2c1.8 1.8 5.7 4.3 7.9 5.4l3.9-.1 4.5-3.5c1.7-3 5.4-8.9 7.3-11.8l3.6-3.1 1-1.7-2.9-2.6c-1.8-1.4-5.1-4.5-6.7-6l-6.4.3-6.6-2.7a79.3 79.3 0 0 1-10-12.2l-2.7 2.4c-.1.2-.1.8-.4.9l-3.4-2.8c-2.4 0-7.7.7-10 0l.3 2 3.4 1.3-3.3-.4-2.4 1.5-.8 1.6.6 3.6-3.5-6s-3.3-2.9-3.4-2.8l-6 .3h-.5l6.1-6.6-3.4-3-6 .3h-.4l-6.4-2.9-3.2.2-3.4-3-3.2.2a498 498 0 0 0-.6-12.2c-1.9-.1-5.8.6-7.7 1-.6 1.9-3.2 4.3-4.4 5.6z" class="noclick"></path>
            <path d="m459.6 205.2-9.2.4c-1.9-1.1-5.2-4.6-7-6l-3.3-2.8-2.8.1c-.3.5-3.8-6.2-4-6.2l-4.6 5.1-4 .4-6 4.3-.4.3v-.1l-.5.1-.4-9.2-3.1 3.1-3 .1-3.3-3.5-7 3 .1 4.4-1.8 1.6v1l-.4.4-.3-6.3c-.2-.1-3.2-3.1-3.4-2.6a29 29 0 0 0-6.4 2.4l-2.7 2.5c0 .2.2 1.5-.1 1.7l-3.4-3.2c-.3-.1-6.7.5-6.6.1l-1 1.7-3.6 3.1-4 6.2-3.3 5.5-4.5 3.5-3.9.1a35.7 35.7 0 0 1-7.9-5.4l-3.2-1.2-3 .9-6.6 5c-2.6.5-7.7 2.3-10.1 3.3l-2.6 4.3-.4 5-2.4 5.6c.9.5 4.1.2 5.1.1l2 2.7-.9 2.8 4.1 4.3-4.6 2.1 1.5 2.2-.6-1.4 7.3 4.7.5.4h.9l3.1 2.6 2.2-.1c1.7 1.3 4.9 4.2 6.4 5.7.1.4 6.1-.2 6.4-.1l7.9-.3 8-3.1 2.8-.2-2-2.6 1.9-1 .3-3 4.9-.8 4.5.4 6.7-.3 6-3.5 3-3.3 6.3-3.5a185 185 0 0 0 5.9-6.6l-.1-2.9 3.3-3.3 15.8-.7 6.2-.2.2 3.2 3.2-.2c.1.3 1.1.1 1.3.1l2.6 2.4 5.7-2.9.8.3.5-.3.6-.3 1.5 1.7 3.1 1.2.5 1.2.6-4.5-1.2-2 .9-3.6 1.5-2.8 2.8-.1-1-3.8 1.8-2.4 3.4-2.2-.7-2.2-1.5 2.3-1.3-4.9z" class="noclick"></path>
            </svg>

        <div class="hotspoters">
            <div class="clickspoter hot2" onclick="showInfo(2)"><div class="hotspoter"></div></div>
            <div class="clickspoter hot3" onclick="showInfo(3)"><div class="hotspoter"></div></div>
            <div class="clickspoter hot4" onclick="showInfo(4)"><div class="hotspoter"></div></div>
            <div class="clickspoter hot5" onclick="showInfo(5)"><div class="hotspoter"></div></div>
            <div class="clickspoter hot6" onclick="showInfo(6)"><div class="hotspoter"></div></div>
    
            <h3 class="ctr2">Belgien</h3>
            <h3 class="ctr3">Niederlande</h3>
            <h3 class="ctr4">Östrreich</h3>
            <h3 class="ctr5">Deutschland</h3>
            <h3 class="ctr6">Polen</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="map-overlay" id="map-overlay" onclick="showInfo()"></div>
        <div class="map-info" id="map-info">
            <span class="map-btn" onclick="closeInfo()">X</span>
            <div class="map-details">
                <div class="country-name" id="country-name"></div>
                <div class="city-name" id="city-name"></div>
                <p class="address-info" id="address-info"></p>
                <p class="tel-info" id="tel-info"></p>
                <p class="tel-info" id="tel-info-2"></p>
                <a href="#" id="call-button" class="call-button" onclick="callButtonClick()">Anrufen</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    
      </div></section>
```

I try to use px, vw, vmin, rem, etc.
I try to change SVG.
I try to use different display modes on different divs, but nothing works for me

P.S. Purple squares are only to show clickable area.

Comment: Please create a snippet in which we can experience the issue for ourselfs. Look for the `<>` icon in the question editor.

Comment: Oh, okay, just done. But I think you don't see the problem even if you run this code from there

Comment: just to narrow down the cause of the problem, can you try removing the css rule for `.hotspoter` and see if makes any difference? I'm not sure to understand the actual issue but since you talked about _blinking_ maybe the animation is behaving in an odd way?

Comment: but also judging from the screenshot given, it seems like the map is blending with the rest of the document without following the regular flow. Is that the issue you were talking about? in that case the snippet itself doesn't reproduce the real scenario since it's just focused on the map itself and not its container

Comment: @DiegoD It's the animiation issues. Damn any idea how to fix it?